# Azure data factory copy activity custom schema name for auto created tables

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We are loading a set of tables from ADLS Gen 2 to Azure Synapse via ADF, using copy activity with auto create table option.
As a result we receive target tables stored in dbo schema.

Is there an approach to customize target schema name (e.g. we wanna load to stg) during table auto creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by parameterizing the Schema and Table name in the Sink (SQL) dataset.

**Data set parameters tab:**

[image]

**Data set connection tab:**

[image]

**Copy activity sink tab:**

[image]

**NOTE**: these would typically be variables or parameters.

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb since did the trick for table  name there, but forgot to specify a schema.
Thank you for pointing!